# To serialize or not

Tags: java, serialization

I have a small desktop application that needs to keep some simple but structured data (>10K) for a single user.  I'd like some opions as to whether I should serialize the objects or build out some XML data files.  I started to serialize things for simplisity and it works but thought I'd ask the community as well for some feedback.  Are there drawbacks or potential problems I may be missing?

Comment: I fear this is a perfect example for a question that will be closed for [not being constructive](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

Comment: I thought the same after I posted it.

Comment: Simple serialization of objects and saving them as binary data leaves your application vulnerable to changes in implementation of these classes. Once you modify them, you may have a hard time getting old data to load properly. I'd go with XML. It's readable, it's a universal format and it provides you with a lot of flexibility. There's also very little programming overhead if you take care to define your format in DTD or XML Schema. Frameworks like JAXB will do most of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I began to wonder about moderate use and extendibility issues, but hadn't run into them specifically yet. It just didn't "feel" right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is to go with **file based database**. One I tried is HSQLDB which is purely java based.

You can use it with JDBC & be privileged to use SQLs.

You dnot need any database installation, it just takes one jar file thats it & it create separate file with your data.

Example: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/apb.html

Note: **Serialization is not for persistence**. If somehow your class changes, it will be very hard to deserialize & it will be as good as data loss.

Answer (score 4):

XML is one choice among many for serialization.  You can do Java Serializable, XML, JSON, protobuf, or anything else that you'd like.  I see no pitfalls.

One advantage of XML is you can use JAXB to marshal and unmarshal objects.

Comment: Serialization is not good for persistence.

Comment: Why not?  Sounds fine for this limited use case.  Simpler than a database.

Comment: Well, if you make changes in the class that you persisted, de-serialization will be a mess. It won't work. Serialization is good for transferring objects like RMI etc. WHere you serialize-transfer-deserialize & you are done. But long term storage is not reliable.

Comment: @RaviK - your description of the issues of serialization is an over simplification.

Comment: Read my answer again.  Java serializable is just one choice.  You can certainly do duck typing with XML and JSON.  And you don't have any idea of how static or dynamic the user's classes will be.  "Do the simplest thing that can possibly work" might apply here.

Answer (score 2):

One major drawback of using Java's serialization mechanism is that it tightly couples to your Java classes. If you make a new version of your application in which you've changed your Java classes, for example you add or remove member variables, then you can't read the files that were written with the older version anymore. For this reason, serialization is not so good for long-term storage.

The format in which Java serializes the data is a non-standard format, which means it will be hard to do anything with it with non-Java tools.

Comment: your description of the drawbacks of serialization is a bit simplistic.  you _can_ deal with class evolution over time, but it is by no means simple.

Answer (score 1):

A third alternative is to use JSON, with a Jackson parser to quickly deserialize to/serialize from a Java object.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere XML files to store Data, because you implement the load and save system yourself. If you change the Structure of your Object(for example adding and Integer, that does not infect the behavior of the used data), all old Object saved by serialisation are useless, because they do not fit to your Class anymore. But using a self designed XML storing system, you can still create you Objects from the old saved data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a good understanding of the trade offs.  Serialization is easier but not as extendable as XML.  If this is a school project or an app for your own use I would personally go with serialization.

You should also consider whether it is appropriate for users to be able to read/edit the XML.  You may want to take steps to prevent that.

You should look at xStream.  I have used it on a couple of projects.